# Problema com encoding na pasta de um arquivo

Tags: r, codificação-de-caracteres

Troquei hoje de computador no serviço e meus códigos pararam de funcionar, dando erro de encoding na pasta dos arquivos:

```
> setwd("I:/AGG/01. DIGEP/Relatórios Gerenciais/Edição/2018-08-17")
> getwd()
[1] "I:/AGG/01. DIGEP/Relatórios Gerenciais/Edição/2018-08-17"
> listao <- read_csv2('listao.csv', locale = locale(encoding = 'latin1'), col_types = cols(.default = col_character())) %>% clean_names
Using ',' as decimal and '.' as grouping mark. Use read_delim() for more control.
Error in guess_header_(datasource, tokenizer, locale) : 
  Cannot read file I:/AGG/01. DIGEP/RelatÃ³rios Gerenciais/EdiÃ§Ã£o/2018-08-17/listao.csv: O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado.
```

Alguém tem ideia de como resolver isso? Sei que sem um código reproduzível é difícil, mas não creio que consiga reproduzir esse erro em outro computador.

Comment: Rode `list.files("I:\\AGG\\01. DIGEP\\Relatórios Gerenciais\\Edição\\2018-08-17")` e/ou `list.files("I:/AGG/01.\\ DIGEP/Relatórios\\ Gerenciais/Edição/2018-08-17")` para verificar se o problema é na codificação dos acentos ou nos espaços.

Comment: Apenas o 1o listou arquivos, o 2o deu vazio. Pelo que eu pude ver é um problema do read_csv2 (pacote readr), pois os outros comandos (read.csv2, por ex) funcionam. Tive que voltar para uma versão do R mais antiga.

Comment: Acabo de me deparar com este pacote que pode lhe ser útil: https://github.com/jennybc/here_here

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto:

```
arquivoDados <- 'I:\\AGG\\01. DIGEP\\Relatórios Gerenciais\\Edição\\2018-08-17\\listao.csv'
listao <- read_csv2(arquivoDados, ...
```

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro